# Renaming a shared folder via /drive/v2/files PATCH - change reflected with delay in the API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the Drive v2 REST API in a .NET application that allows seeing your Google Drive content in a file-picker manner. The scenario I have is the following:

- I am renaming a folder that was shared with me (editor rights) making a PATCH request to /www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[folderID] on the title property
- The request is successful and the rename is instantly visible on the Google Drive website
- In my application, when refreshing the parent folder's contents to see the change, it is not visible immediately - during my tests it took anywhere between 1 and 5 minutes for it to show.

Remarks:

1. If I make the change using Google Drive's website, it is reflected instantly through the API
2. I do not experience the delay on my own folders, only on folders that were shared with me by other users.

Is this a known issue of the API? Is there a workaround perhaps? Would upgrading to v3 help in this case?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. If I make the change using Google Drive's website, it is reflected instantly through the API

It can but there is normal a delay.

> 2. I do not experience the delay on my own folders, only on folders that were shared with me by other users.

This is probably because the sheared folder system is larger and needs to update a cross more people.

If your worried to much about it i would post an issue about it on the [forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B) but you should post an example of your code that shows it running and how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

### There are performance and some other differences

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v3versusv2) says `The performance in v3 is better because searches only return a subset of fields. Use the current version unless you need the apps collection`.

In your specific case, by using [version 3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) is better than [version 2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch#.net) when it comes to performance because you are not using the **apps** resource. Keep in mind that sometimes your connection may affect the performance (Once you click the TRY API in the website, Google is in charge of making the request, on the other side when using your .NET project makes the request and it can take a little bit more time)

### Reference

[Drive API v3 versus v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v3versusv2)

[V2 to v3 differences](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference)

[How to migrate v2 to v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/migrate-to-v3)